# Either Usage & Error Handling in Java

Tags: java, java-8, either

My goal is to use the Either class alongside my Human, Weapon, and Magazine classes.

These are the different Human declarations I want to test. (No weapon, no mag, and has all)

```
Human noWeapon = new Human(null);
Human noMag = new Human(new Weapon(null));
Human hasAll = new Human(new Weapon(new Magazine(2)));
```

Currently, I'm creating an Either in the following way:

```
Human noWeapon = new Human(null);
Either <String, Human> either2 = new Right <String, Human>(noWeapon);
Right <String, Human> either2_right = (Right<String, Human>) either2;
```

I'm struggling to understand the inner workings of the Either class and the ways for which I can use it for error handling. I want to be able to catch these errors when they occur so I can know when the error is happening

```
either2_right.getRight().getWeapon().getMag().getCount();
```

Currently, this is throwing a NullPointerException error for obvious reasons - but my goal is to instead catch the error and know when it occured.

My Either class is as follows:

```
abstract class Either<A, B> { }

class Left<A, B> extends Either<A, B> {
    public A left_value;
    public Left(A a) 
    { 
        left_value = a; 
    }

    public A getLeft(){
        return this.left_value;
    }

    public <B2> Either<A,B2> flatMap(final Function<B,Either<A,B2>> f){
      return (Either<A,B2>)this;
  }

  public <B2> Either<A,B2> map(final Function<B,B2> f){
      return (Either<A,B2>)this;
  }
}

class Right<A, B> extends Either<A, B> {
    public B right_value;
    public Right(B b) 
    { 
        right_value = b; 
    }

    public B getRight(){
        return this.right_value;
    }

    public <B2> Either<A,B2> flatMap(final Function<B,Either<A,B2>> f){
      return f.apply(right_value);
  }

  public <B2> Either<A,B2> map(final Function<B,B2> f){
      return new Right(f.apply(right_value));
  }
}
```

I'm using Either for my following 3 classes:
Human

```
class Human {
        Weapon w;

        public Human(Weapon w) 
        { 
            this.w = w; 
        }

        public Weapon getWeapon() 
        {
            return w;
        }
    }
```

Weapon:

```
class Weapon {
        Magazine m;

        public Weapon(Magazine m) 
        { 
            this.m = m; 
        }

        public Magazine getMag() 
        {
            return m;
        }
    }
```

Magazine:

```
class Magazine {
        private int count;

        public Magazine(int c) 
        { 
            count = c; 
        }

        public int getCount() 
        { 
            return count; 
        }
    }
```

Thank you for any help I'm able to get!

Comment: I'm confused. What `Either` class do you use? I'm not aware of one in the standard Java 8 JDK.

Comment: @daniu I'm creating the Either class. The code for it is in my post.

Comment: I saw, but it's still confusing because you're not saying what is supposed to be used for, and even say you're "struggling to understand its inner workings"... So you don't know what you want but since you did something anyway you'd like to understand it?

Comment: @Cole it seems I haven't answered your questions fully, please comment on the answer so I know what to add to make the answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling to understand the inner workings of the Either class and the ways for which I can use it for error handling.

Let us start with the second part of the question, how can I use `Either` for error handling?
`Either` can hold one of two values, for error handling you can declare a method to return an `Either` that will hold a valid computation result or an Exception. For example:

```
public Either<ArithmeticException, Double> divide (Double x, Double y) {
    try {
      return new Right<ArithmeticException, Double>(x/y);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
      return new Left<ArithmeticException, Double>(e);
    }
 }
```

The caller will not get an ArithmeticException if he try to divide by zero, he will receive an `Either` holding the exception, in this example he will get a `Left`. The convention is to hold valid return results in a `Right` and the other results in a `Left`.

The implementation you provided doesn't make it easy for the caller to check if he got a `Right` or a `Left` or make it easy to process the result regardless of it is a `Right` or a '`Left` a more complete implementation of `Either` [here](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/fugue/src/956cecb0af588c9bd70a42ac1645336e24b10e88/fugue/src/main/java/io/atlassian/fugue/Either.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) provides that convenience (for instance `getOrThrow` to get a `Right` value or throw an exception if the `Either` is not a `Right`).